# macOS 10.15.5 printer software list is empty

Tags: macos, printing

I want to add a printer to MacBook Pro using an IP but failed.

I enter the right IP. When I began to select driver by clicking "select software", I found there is nothing in the software list.

Then I check the printer directory, /Library/printers, there are some drivers there. So, it's weird that the software list is empty.

Then I search for some possible reason, some solutions told me to reset the printer and check the printer directory. But they are not helping.

Then I typed

```
lpinfo -v
```

in terminal. It came to an error

```
lpinfo: cups-deviced failed to execute.
```

Then I reinstall CUPS system, but this is not helping either.

I don't know what's wrong with my Mac printer.

I have searched for possible reasons for many days. And there are no relevant answers I want. The question I want to clarify is not I cannot add a printer in macOS. The intrinsic problem is there is no printer driver software in **System Preferences** > **Printers & Scanners** > **Add** > **Use** > **Select Software** > **Software list**. But there are printer drivers in the path: `/Library/Printers` (include Epson, HP). That means there should be some drivers in the software list, but there are not. I asked this question because my colleague and I bought the exact same version of the MacBook Pro 13" at the same time. But there are printer drivers in his software list. (we use the same steps to add a printer! Please note this premise.)

If you still can't understand my question, please leave comments below!

Comment: What is the printer model you want add?

Comment: Can you try to [the printing system](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mh14001/mac) completely?

Comment: Yeah, i did try reset my printer.

Comment: @lpr Just to be clear: I referred to ressetting the whole print system not just the printer. Besides: [here](https://mypantum.com/drivers/) you can download the drivers which work on MacOS 10.15.x.

Comment: @slartibartfast Sorry, I didn't say clearly before, I have done the steps as the link you post, before I ask this question. I have reset printing system, this removed all printers in MAC. And I tried install many drivers with different Pantum versions (p3300, p3500... ...) from Malaysia, global, Chinese Pantum official websites. And all these attempts not working. I have tried all possible solutions I can find on network. Which makes me confused is nobody came to this problem before. So, now, i think this may be the negligence of Mac maker (just guess).

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing to do would be to update Mac Os X to the latest version of Catalina (actually 10.15.7).

Comment: I have to keep my MAC in 10.15.5, because I need to use IDL 71. IDL 71 collapsed when my colleague update his MAC. And there are some solutions told me to check the software update list if I don't want to update system but printer driver. But there are no update choice for printer driver in update list.

Comment: And what is the printer model?

Comment: And another weird thing is, me and my colleague have the exactly same MacBook pro 13, with same operating system version and everything else. But this problem only occur in my Mac. This makes me cannot accept.

Comment: printer is pantum p3000 series.

Comment: Have you try download the printer driver directly from Pantum site, if exist?

Comment: Google finds drivers at https://global.pantum.com/global/drive/p3255dn/ though it's ancient. Apple doesn't list Pantum as supported, so you'll need the drivers… if they still work on a modern OS - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201465

Comment: I don't see why it would try to find drivers for the wrong printer. See https://eclecticlight.co/2018/10/22/how-to-install-a-printer-in-macos-mojave/ for workarounds on old printers that don't support airprint & have no Mac drivers.

Comment: @Jean_JD No, Pantum site doesn't provide driver for this series. And I copy a driver package from others. What confused me is not Pantum, but there are no driver in "software list". Epson and HP driver have been installed in path /Library/Printers, which means there should be Epson and HP driver in "software list"

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, I just learn how to mention somebody here, I paste the comment said days ago. This website has the picture I want to show (I cannot put images here). Please have a look at the website you post. The third picture there. Whichever printer I choose, there should be some printer software driver in the option "select software" , but there are no drivers in mine.